# Load Files Received Every n mins

Tags: hive, apache-pig

I want to process the Files which are received in a HDFS directory in the last 5 mins using Pig/Hive.  For example, I have a different team they are sending XML files Every 5 mins under a HDFS directory. Do i need to try find /path -cmin -5 to load the files? Need guidance.

Comment: What kind of process you are trying to run on the received files? What do you mean by "load the files"? The files are already getting loaded onto HDFS are you trying to load into HBASE or any other NOSql DB? Please explain....

Comment: I want to process all the new files using Pig/Hive every 5 mins as they receive in HDFS.  How do i parameterize this in Pig/Hive. Also, can you suggest me how to Load XML data into Hbase every 5 mins as they receive in HDFS?